# Unable to REBOOT a device using Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am trying to reboot a device using the enterprise ID and device ID. Below is the request parameter

Screenshot from Android Management API guide Try It feature

[image: Screenshot from Android Management API guide Try It feature]

I don't see any action on the device end. If there is any alternate approach or if anyone had a successful attempt in this process, please let me know the process you followed.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the basic steps mentioned in the below link given by android management api?

https://developers.google.com/android/management

If yes for above, check the below options,
1 Check your device internet connection. 
   It should be connected to a network
2 check is there any error after you submit
3 How did you enroll your device

Answer (score 0):

Tried this exact code and device reboots in seconds. Try checking the parameters of your request to make sure the device id is correct. You can also set a longer duration to allow more time for the command to go through in case of delay or connectivity issues.

```
projectid = [Your-projectid-here] 
enterprises/LC03nfv2bi/devices/33395ba163dde778 
{
   "type": "REBOOT",
   "duration": "600s"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#1-device-provisioning this feature is only available on android 7.0+.

[image: android reboot device documentation]

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the next URL with POST:
https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/LC00XXXXX/devices/32e2bXXXXXXXXX:issueCommand

And this json in the request body

```
{  "type": "REBOOT" }
```